# Deploy to App Engine trouble - You must be logged in to perform this action

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, deployment, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android Studio and have just runned through the tutorial 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints
without much trouble.

However, when I try to deploy my backend to the app server it promts me: "You must be logged in to perofrm this action".

[image]

I have no idea of why it teels that. I can easely find me project on the list, and Im logged in to my google acount on various browsers including Chrome.

Have seached the internet, but found no one else with the problem before.

Best Regards Allan

Comment: I haven't looked in Android Studio + App Engine in a while, but there used to be a "add account" button. Maybe that's what you need? It used to be at the bottom of the list of projects.

Comment: Usually clicking on the "Deploy to:" combo box triggers a sign it so you can actually access your list of projects. Did you fill that in manually or by selecting it?

In android studio you can also login by clicking on the little silhouette in the top right corner.

Comment: You were right. Clicking "add account" helped. Fill stupid, but I had added account earlier to access my projects. I dont know why it was nessesary to add account twice. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @AllanNielsen it's possible some kind of auth token got expired and needed a "kick" to properly refresh. I've posted my comment as a fleshed out answer :). Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your auth has been done a little while ago and the system cannot properly see you authenticated anymore, which would explain such a behavior.

At the bottom of the list of projects, you should see a "add account" button. Click on this and just re-auth. Should clear the bad tokens :).

Comment: can you please tell me where can we see  the add account button in the android studio or in the webpage??

Answer (score 0):

Steps For Intrgration of App Engine Endpoints Module.
.....................................................

1-:Create an Google Devloper Console Account.Create a new project after completing the project  creation they give you a Project id and project no.
2-:Open Android Studio File-->New-->New Project.
3-:After Project creation is completed Right Click On your project select Module-->Google Cloud Module as shown in images folder chouse_module image.
4-:When you Select The Google Cloud Module Then choose "App Engine Java Endpoints Module".as shown in images folder endpoints image.
5-:As soon as the backend module is added to your project and Gradle sync finishes,a new run configuration with your backend's module is created.
6-:Rebuild your project via "Build → Rebuild Project"
7-:Now Check Your Backend started sucesfully  naivigate to http://localhost:8080.if your Backend started sucessfully you saw the screen as as shown in images folder devappserver-endpoints image.

Connecting your Backend to your android project.
...........................................................

8-:After Backend Module is created and added strong libraries is automatically genrated for you.
9-:To start sending requests to the added Cloud Endpoints backend API.you Have to created one Async Class in your Project file.you Can Get the Async task class in required Packages folder with name AsynctaskClass.java 
10-:To make the actual call, invoke this AsyncTask from one of your Android activities.In this way :: new EndpointsAsyncTask().execute(new Pair(this, "Message"));
11-:Ckeck that you granted an internet permission in menifest or not.
12-:Now check that you have accese to local host as shown in point 7.
13-:Its time to Check in Emulator Change your Run confrigation and run your project If everything goes well, you should see the following toast in your app as shown in images folder emulator-Toast image.

Deploying the backend live to App Engine
......................................................

14-:If your backend is working locally, you can deploy it to Google App Engine.
    Stop the backend, if it is running locally, by selecting Run > Stop.
    Than navigate to  Build > Deploy Module to App Engine.
15-:update your src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml file's  property and replace myApplicationId with the ID of the project that you just created.as shown in point 1.
16-: you can see the screen as shown in images folder deploy-image image.
17-:In the Deploy to you have to select the project you created on Google Devloper Console.as shown in point 1.  
18-:Put the version name and click deploy Button.
19-:Once you have deployed your backend to App Engine, you can connect your Android app to it by modifying AsyncTask class defined in point 9 replace the perticular lines shown in ReplaceCode.java file in required Packages folder.
20-:Now you can communicate with your new App Engine backend!.
For More Info -:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints.
https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/add_module?hl=en.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.
I have manage to get to your point 18 and the click deploy Button. Thats when it promts to me "You must be logged in to perform this action". But where to log in?

Answer (score 0):

Ive never used android studio but Im sure its like eclipse sdk puglin.
There is an easy way to deploy ur apps on ur mobile device, but before u get to that point u need to eanable android mobile on debug mode (On settings,developer options).Once u have done that, Im pretty sure there is an option which lets u run ur app on android device making much smother than doing it virtual app.

Hope I helped ya...

Answer (score 0):

Use the gradle commands.

Open the terminal within android studio and run

```
gradlew appengine:update
```

Or navigate to the gradle project window and look for the google appengine folder under your backend. And double click the appengineUpdate command.

[image: Example gradle/android studio]

Adding the backend with android studio should automatically add the appengine plugin for gradle in your backend build.gradle file like this. This plugin is allows you to run the appengine update command.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue using  Android Studio Ver2.2 in Ubuntu 14.04

I was not able to do sign-in into Android Studio using the SignIn icon from top-left of the Android Studio IDE.  When signin icon clicked, a pop-up says that Sign-in using external browser but nothing would pop-up.

Build->Deploy to app Engine->Deploy to tab was also showing the same message as above but no browser would pop up

Even gradlew api:appengineUpdate was not working. (no browser would pop up).

Problem got resolved by changing the File->Setting->Web Browsers (it was listing browsers Chrome, Firefox, Safari in that order). The Default Browser was set to "First listed". I unchecked the chrome and my problem got solved, I was able sign-in and deploy my project.

I spent lot of time finding solution for this, thought it might help others, so posting it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I did not realize it at first but when you get this message, you simply click on the dropdown "Deploy To", and then it invites you to log into your google account.
It is not very intuitive if your project is already selected by default.